# Meteor React Error: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, meteor, meteor-react

On a very simple Meteor app using React, there is a table that list out all the registered users from the `Meteor.users` collection.

However when trying to display the email address of each user, the browser JS console is throwing the following error, although the email address is correctly rendered on the HTML page.

```
Exception from Tracker recompute function:
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Users.render (User.jsx:8)
```

Why is this error happening?

**/imports/ui/User.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Users extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{ this.props.user._id}</td>
                <td>{ this.props.user.emails[0].address }</td>  // this is line 8
            </tr>
        )
    }
}
```

**/imports/ui/App.jsx**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

import User from './User';

export class App extends Component {

    renderUsers() {
        return this.props.users.map((user) => (
            <User key={user._id} user={user} />
        ));
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Users</h1>

                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ID</td>
                            <td>Email</td>
                        </tr>
                        { this.renderUsers() }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

App.propTypes = {
    users: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}

export default createContainer(() => {
    return {
        users: Meteor.users.find().fetch()
    }
}, App);
```

Comment: Perhaps the User component's render method are getting called twice  once before the emails has been resolved and the second time after it has been resolved. Try putting a console.log(this.props) in your User component's render method

Comment: How is it so far? What's the log value of this.props.user. Most times it may be that the email attribute hasn't been sent to the client.

Comment: @Swapnil Adding `console.log` as suggested, I get `Object {users: Array[0]}` followed by `Object {users: Array[1]}`

Comment: Using `_.get` seems to solve the problem. Wondering if there is an alternative to the lodash solution.

Comment: @Nyxynyx Sorry my bad. I meant do a console.log(this.props.user.emails)

Comment: @Swapnil No worries, think it kind of explained the error too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it would seem `this.props.user.emails` is undefined. are you sure this is the correct key you are looking for?

ways to fix this.

pull in a library like lodash (it will change your life)

```
import _ from 'lodash';
....
<td>{_.get(this.props, 'users.emails[0].address', 'UNKNOWN ADDRESS')}</td>
```

if you dont want to pull in something like lodash then check to see if the value is there..

```
var address = 'UNKNOWN ADDRESS';
if(this.props.users.emails && this.props.users.emails.length > 0) {
     address = this.props.users.emails[0].address;
}
```

Comment: Its the correct key, being undefined when the `renderUsers()` function is called the first time, then defined when its called again the second time.

Comment: As an alternative to using lodash's `_.get`, is there a way to let React render the components only when the collection has been retrieved?

Comment: @Nyxynyx yea if you want to conditionally render the users based on if their info has loaded or not then just put in a check to see if the user email is there.. if it isn't then dont render the item

Comment: @Nyxynyx I would still regardless of another way to do it HIGHLY recommend you pull in lodash. it will make your life way easier as a developer. I have 0 javascript errors in my web sights because I use things like `_.get`... plus they have many iterators and ways to order data. just a very useful tool :)

Comment: I'm using lodash and `_,get` :) Where is a good place to import lodash so it overwrites underscore? I currently have `_ = lodash;` in `client/main.jsx`

Comment: @Nyxynyx do you have underscore and lodash? They both try to do the same thing. I would just stick with one. Obv my preference is lodash. If you were going to use both just call lodash something else. aka `import lodash from 'lodash';` and then it would be `lodash.get(...)`

Comment: I always thought that underscsore came with Meteor, so I have access to the `_` functions without having to manually import underscore

Comment: @Nyxynyx ah I see what you're saying. well you could try to define `window._ = lodash` or just import lodash everywhere you want to use it